# How Do I add a Single Quotations to a Field Reference?

Tags: microsoft-excel

*Currently I have this:*

```
= "Account ="&A2
```

Which looks like this:

```
Account = 123123123123
```

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
Account = '123123123123'
```

How Do I add the single quote, i.e., `'` in between the `&A2`?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When constructing a text string in Excel, cell references go by themselves and anything else goes inside double quotes. You connect the pieces (as you already know) using `&`.

So for your example, just include single quotes inside double quotes where you need them:

`= "Account ='"&A2&"'"`

Comment: Perfect, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to concatenate the strings together like this:

`=CONCAT( "Account ="," '",A2,"'")`

Which provides the desired outcome

[image]

Comment: Perfect, Thank you!

Comment: Feel free to mark the answer and/or upvote it.